# How do I style all anchor tags inside a certain div?

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out how to properly do this. I have the following CSS:

```
#container > #main > #content > a {
    color: #3B7315;
}
```

I'm using that to supposedly style all `<a>` tags in the `#content` div. The problem is, however, it doesn't seem to style `<a>` tags inside divs or nested lists, etc. It only styles the top-most tags such as the following:

```
<div id="content">
     <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
</div>
```

When I put the link inside another element, the styling is gone.

So how do I include the whole sub elements and make the style recursively apply itself from `#content` onwards? I think I'm looking for a wildcard value of sort?

Comment: > only matches first level children, not all descendants. also if you're using ids, you really only need to use the last id

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You made it much more complicated than it needs to be:

```
#content a {}
```

Comment: The ">" in css means the style will only apply to immediate children. So removing the ">" sign as John has shown will work. This will include all children

Answer (score 5):

```
#content a, #content a:link, #content a:visited {base style rules}
#content a:hover, #content a:visited:hover, #content a:active {over style rules}
#content a:focus {wai style rules}
```

Answer (score 2):

All that is necessary is the container and its anchors you are trying to style. The following should work fine, especially if that div you are using is an id, because then it wont be repeated onto other elements, as it would if you had a class on that div and other divs.

```
#content a{ style rules; }
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

the symbol > is only applies to the direct child..that's why if you use that it would be only applied to the first child a of the element id content